# Add UIButton to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, uibutton, calayer, subview, avcapturesession

I want to add a UIButton or other type of button to an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Here is what I have tried:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];
UIButton * sButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 100)];
[sButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[sButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_videoPreviewLayer addSublayer:sLabel.layer];
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

I also tried something similar with a UIView which was added, even when the AVCapture was not started. I could not however add a subview to that view.

Comment: Why don't you add the button on the containerView.layer of videoPreviewLayer?

Comment: That could work. How do I do that? videoPreviewLayer.containerview.layer does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but I've been working on something similar, so I thought I'd share:

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[btn becomeFirstResponder];
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,  btn);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```